# Какой ccs файл подключать ко второй .html странице?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Есть две HTML страницы

```
index.html
item.html
```

А также скомпилированный `main.min.css` файл, подключенный к `index.html`.

Я не до конца понимаю, нужно ли продолжать писать стили в `main.min.css`, а после подключать его к `item.html`.
Но тогда получается, что я нагромождаю `main.min.css` и основная страница будет грузиться дольше.

Стоит ли подключать к `item.html` отдельный css файл?
Просто шапка и футер одинаковые на всем сайте.

Comment: Как по мне, "грузиться дольше" и CSS - это паранойя. Хотя с другой стороны, я ещё не писал один CSS файл больше 500 строк (пишу построчно).. upd, вру, есть один на 600 :D

Comment: Один вариант - лепить все в общий файл, второй вариант - для каждой страницы отдельный файл. Возможно есть и другие варианты.

Answer (score 1):

В своей практике я делаю так, сначала есть общий стиль, например common.css  для страницы index.htm, а к примеру если страница item.htm  подключаю common.css(в обязательном порядке) и для него  создаю уже item.css , чтобы через эти стили модифицировать другие компоненты, блоки . То есть, основной есть,  но уже для отдельных страниц вам легче будет вносить изменения, как бы избегая copy-paste. Вполне оправданная практика

Comment: и ловите репорт от GooglePageSpeed за слишком большое кол-во файлов, ПРОФИТ!

Answer (score 1):

Лично моё мнение.

CSS, если использовать "обычные" свойства не такой уж и "тяжёлый".
Да и делать `***.min.css` - паранойя.. Имхо.

---

Вы можете написать три CSS:
Один для общих элементов (body, header, footer, input'ы (допустим),
Второй, отдельный, для страницы `index.html`,
Ну и третий для страницы `item.html`.

Ну а дальше подключать к страницы по два CSS.

---

По ответу [@John](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/952477/221218), решил дополнить..

Я обычно делаю один CSS файл для всех страниц и его содержимое выглядит примерно так:

```
Стили для элементов, таких как body, заголовки, инпуты, текстзоны и т.п.
"Главная страница", т.е. стили для той страницы, которую видит юзер.
Стили для других страниц.
"Доп. стили" или "фикс стили", такие как фикс инлайнов (clear: both), анимация и т.п.
Ну и в самом конце обычно key-frame
```

Обычно это работает нормально, без каких-то долгих обработок..
Возможно потому, как я уже писал в комментах, не помню чтобы делал CSS больше 600 строк (пишу построчно).

Answer (score 0):

Если твоя страница отличаеться каким-то одним(несколькими блоками) это не сильно нагромоздит `main.min.css`, а вот +1запрос на второй фаил будет куда тяжелее для страницы.

Держи в "главном/основном" файле общие стили, например сетку, типографику, меню и прочие элементы доступные на всех страницах. Если есть какой-то уникальный блок на одной странице - смело добавляй в основной фаил этот код, если же там очень много уникального контента - в другой фаил `item.min.css` например, для упращения понимания можешь делать на каждую страницу отдельный фаил и либо использовать `@include` подключать его в основной, либо компилировать отдельный.